# Remove item price from bundled products in pdf invoice (magento)

Tags: magento, pdf

In my pdf invoice in Magento after every item of an bundled product I get the price, in my situation $0.00 How can I remove that?
I found out that the products are written by $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order); in Invoice.php

How can I remove the $0.00 from my pdf invoice?

Thank you so much!

Comment: what magento version do you have ?

Answer (score 2):

Renderers for each product type defined in the config. Default renderer and for grouped product type are defined in the `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml`:

```
<pdf>
    <invoice>
        <default>sales/order_pdf_items_invoice_default</default>
        <grouped>sales/order_pdf_items_invoice_grouped</grouped>
    </invoice>
    ...
</pdf>
```

For bundle product type in the `app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/etc/config.xml`:

```
<pdf>
    <invoice>
        <bundle>bundle/sales_order_pdf_items_invoice</bundle>
    </invoice>
    ...
</pdf>
```

And corresponding model is `Mage_Bundle_Model_Sales_Order_Pdf_Items_Invoice`

You can create own renderer extends from this model in your *local* namespace, copy and make changes to the `draw()` method and define this renderer in your config file.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look in Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option and modify the getPrice functions, but to do so properly requires a class rewrite, which is another topic entirely.  A good starting point for rewrites is something like this reference: http://codemagento.com/2011/02/rewriting-a-block-class/